# Fazer login na rede Wifi pelo aplicativo

Tags: java, android

Quando se conecta a uma rede wifi que necessita de autenticação, o Android te envia para a página de autenticação da rede por um redirecionamento enviado geralmente pelo link *connectivitycheck.gstatic.com/generate_204* ou pelo link *clients3.google.com/generate_204* ou links semelhantes.

No aplicativo que estou desenvolvendo, quero fazer isso de forma automática pelo app. Quero que ele consiga o endereço redirecionado e faça o login na rede usando esse endereço.

Como posso fazer para, dentro do aplicativo, acessar esses links e pegar o link para qual eles redirecionam, tudo em background?

Além disso, como posso fazer para verificar, em tempo de execução, se o usuário está logado e com acesso a rede wifi?

> **Edição para complementar:** Vou descrever melhor a situação no contexto.
>
> Meu aplicativo tem salvo o login e senha do usuário. Assim, ele abre
>   internamente a página de login do wifi e faz o login com as
>   informações salvas. O problema é justamente ter conhecido o url.
>
> Esse problema acontece pois nunca é a mesma url. Ela muda a cada
>   tentativa de login, devido ao token diferente que é gerado a cada
>   login.
>
> Meu objetivo é, de alguma forma, conseguir essa url para enviar para a
>   função de login, e assim saber o url para enviar para a função.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom dia.
Não entendi se automaticamente ao conectar no wifi já abre o browser na tela de login ou se a tela de login aparece ao tentar navegar após conectar no wifi. 
Se for a segunda opção, vc pode criar uma serviço android q fica "escutando" qual rede wifi o aparelho se conectou. Após detectar que houve uma conexão naquela rede, vc pode:

1. fazer uma requisição http qualquer só para cair na tela de login e pegar o
   endereço (utilizei org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet e org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost)
2. procurar pelo url q o "botao de login" aponta (se já souber, não precisa fazer isso)
3. enviar os dados de login (da mesma forma/mesmos parametros que o form faz na pagina, provavelmente por POST)
4. tratar o retorno (no caso de um cookie, ou token, armazena-lo/utiliza-lo corretamente para proximas requisições)

Segue um exemplo (já sabia a URL do POST para logar):

```
logger.info("Logando...");

HttpPost post = getHttpPost(System.getProperty(Propriedades.urlLogin));

List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_username", System.getProperty(Propriedades.urlUsername)));
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_password", System.getProperty(Propriedades.urlSenha)));

post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

Header header = response.getFirstHeader("Location");
if ( header == null || !Strings.nullToEmpty(header.getValue()).contains(urlLogin) )
    throw new LoginSenhaInvalidosException(System.getProperty(Propriedades.urlUsername), System.getProperty(Propriedades.urlSenha));


int initIndex = header.getValue().indexOf("jsessionid=");           
sessao = header.getValue().substring(initIndex, header.getValue().indexOf("?", initIndex));

logger.info("Logon OK");
```

Nesse exemplo, estou fazendo um POST para a url que o botao de login na pagina aponta. Nesse POST, estou enviando o username e senha. Após o POST, eu checo a resposta e vejo no header do response se tem um redirecionamento para a pagina de login, se tiver, nao houve logon, se nao tiver, houve.

Comment: Vou descrever melhor a situação no contexto.

Meu aplicativo tem salvo o login e senha do usuário. Assim, ele abre internamente a página de login do wifi e faz o login com as informações salvas, de uma forma realmente bem semelhante ao que você apresentou no seu código. O problema é justamente ter conhecido o url.

Esse problema acontece pois nunca é a mesma url. Ela muda a cada tentativa de login, devido ao token diferente que é gerado a cada login.

Meu objetivo é, de alguma forma, conseguir essa url para enviar para a função de login, e assim saber o url para enviar para a função.

Comment: Acredito q se vc fizer uma requisição http pra qualquer endereço [q requeira estar logado antes], no cabeçalho ou no body do response (não lembro de cabeça agora) virá a URL de login (pois é assim q o browser descobre pra qual URL deve te redirecionar). Observe bem o response, principalmente o header dele. Assim vc pode obter a URL, salvar em uma variavel e fazer uma nova requisição http pra ela.

Comment: Poderia fazer um código de exemplo de como fazer isso? Apenas um rascunho já ajudaria

Comment: Ué, o exemplo de cima nao ajuda?